# ¿Cómo escapar la palabra Todo, todo en los comentarios de PHPStorm?

Tags: ide

¿Cómo evitar que PHPStorm 2017.1 cambie la coloración de esa palabra identificandola con las tareas pendientes por hacer? Emplear algo como, @Todo para que el Ide no la reconozca, la manera más simple es ponerla con alguna h o de lo contrario escribirlo en ingles, pero no creo que sea la mejor solución ya que debe haber alguna más óptima. Gracias

Comment: Si buscas opiniones, puedes realizar esta pregunta en el [chat].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En `Preferences > Editor > TODO` puedes editar la palabra `todo` por ejemplo a `TODO` y hacerlo `Case Sensitive` o configurarlo a tu gusto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perfecto, nada que agregar, gracias!!!!